# Copy task in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008-sp1

This is a question related to a previous question I posted (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251983/batch-files-in-visual-studio-2008)).
I need to configure a .csproj file to copy some files from a directory to another one (let me call them SOURCE and DESTINATION). I also need to change the SOURCE path depending from the configuration I'm using. For example, if I compile my project in Debug mode, the SOURCE path must contain a subfolder called Debug.
I tried the solution proposed by Schmitt in the previous post, using $(ConfigurationName) to set the dynamic directory into the SOURCE path. When I opened the solution containing that project, a list of links to the source files appeared in the main tree of the project and they were correctly related to the Debug mode. But when I changed to the Release mode, I saw that the path of the linked source files were set again to the Debug version.
Is there a way to specify a parameter in the Include attribute of the SourceFiles element?
Thank you.

Comment: Please paste the two directives/commands that you are using for the copy task.

Comment: <ItemGroup>
<MySourceFiles Include="\\servername\directory\$(ConfigurationName)\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="CopyFiles">
<Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)Dlls" />
</Target>